# How to convert quaternion between coordinate systems

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, coordinate-systems, 3dsmax

I have a quaternion, coming from a system with the following: (Unity)

```
Left-handed.
Forward direction: Z axis
Right direction: X axis
Up direction: Y axis
```

I need to convert this into a coordinate system that is: (3ds max)

```
Right-handed.
Forward direction: Y axis
Right direction: X axis
Up direction: Z axis
```

I have tried negating the axis, and angle, I have tried switching values, I cannot get this to work. All help greatly appreciated! I am working in C#

Comment: Do you really need to do this programmatically?  In 3ds max you can rotate the pivot so it aligns with unitys coordinate system, regardless of the orientation of the original mesh.

Comment: Yes, I need this. Please help

Comment: Have you tried those https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157946/converting-a-quaternion-in-a-right-to-left-handed-coordinate-system